# Escaped regex is not working for this specific case

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check for percentage between 20 to 50 (both included and decimals are allowed as well) in my JS code.

I created a regex for this `/^[2-4]\d(\.\d\d?)?|50(\.00?)?$/`

This regex successfully works, but I need to add this to JSON file, so I'm escaping it.

Escaped regex is `/^[2-4]\\d(\\.\\d\\d?)?|50(\\.00?)?$/`

Now the issue is that escaped regex is not working to detect the required values.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Double escaped regex should be `^(?:[2-4]\\d(?:\\.\\d\\d?)?|50(?:\\.00?)?)$`

Comment: Please show exactly how it occurs in JSON, and what you do with it when you parse the JSON. It should be possible to make a runnable snippet (use the toolbar) with an actual (very small) JSON and the code that parses it, and executes the regex, and reproduces the issue.

Comment: @trincot "inputRegex": "/^[2-4]\\d(\\.\\d\\d?)?|50(\\.00?)?$/", this is how it looks like in the JSON file

Comment: Can you edit your question and maybe even create a runnable snippet using the toolbar, so we see the problem occur when we run it?

Comment: The first issue is that the forward slashes should not be there. Those are delimiters for when you use a regex **literal**, not when it is a string that is parsed as a regex.